# jest is not reading props properly and showing: console.error Warning: React does not recognize the `navHeading` prop on a DOM element

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am passing the props like this

```
<Tag navHeading>
</Tag>
```

This works when I run with npm run start and takes navHeading=true.

This error occurs only with jest

How to fix this?

I tried looking up docs and stackoverflow. I want navHeading prop to be read as true.

Here is my actual code:

```
// StyledComponents.js
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
const StyledTypography = withTheme(styled(Typography).attrs((props) => ({
}))`
  ${(props) => {
    if (props.navHeading) 
      return `SOME TEXT`
      
  }}
`);
export {StyledTypography};
```

Navbar.js

```
// Navbar.js
import { StyledTypography } from "./StyledComponents";
class NavBar extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <>
            <StyledTypography navHeading>
                HELLO WORLD
            </StyledTypography>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

My test
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen, prettyDOM, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

```
describe('Navbar', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
     render(<Navbar />)
   })
});
```

Comment: Can you add more code, at least your test that is failing. and don't you need to do `<Tag navHeadig={someValue} />`

Comment: In test i am just rendering the component. No, I don't need to do so, because it automatically detects navHeading=true

Comment: I'd still recommend adding more code, even if the test seems straightforward

Comment: I have added the code. It works as expected when I run with npm run start. Can you please look into this. Thank you